# Variables within string, python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Normally, i can use the following code to implement a variable within a string

```
print "this is a test %s" % (test)
```

however, it doesn't seem to work as i had to use this

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> test = '!'
>>> print "this is a test %s" % (test)
this is a test !
```

If you import `print_function` feature, `print` acts as function:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print "this is a test %s" % (test)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "this is a test %s" % (test)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You should use function call form after the import.

```
>>> print("this is a test %s" % (test))
this is a test !
```

**SIDE NOTE**

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.format):

> `str.format` is new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the `%` formatting.

```
>>> print("this is a test {}".format(test))
this is a test !
```

Comment: It's a bit funny to use the futuristic "print" syntax but the obsolete "%" format syntax instead of str.format.  :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I add mention about `str.format`. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
print("this is a test", test)
```

Or this:

```
print("this is a test {}".format(test))
```

Comment: @MattWalker With `from __future__ import print_function`, you now replace the `print` statement with its function counterpart. Thus, simply `print some_value % (formatter)` doesn't work. See the answers for what works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing a string use `%s`.

Comment: What is the value of `test`?